# GRUB issue and botrepair won't work

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I'm having some issues with my freshly installed Ubuntu..
It seems GRUB didn't install properly (I installed "alongside windows" in UEFI).
I tried to run bootrepair but it kinda stuck in a loop asking me "Filesystem repair requires to unmount partitions. Please close all your programs. Then close this window.".

I've seen other people experiencing similar problems but as I understand there are several possible causes to it so I decided to be cautious and ask for the help of the Community... 
Please?

here is my magic link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7542427/

You are my only hope... ;)

Comment: How did you try Boot-Repair? To unmount all your partitions you have to start from a external boot media ( CD/DVD or from a USB drive). But perhaps its a UEFI issue https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI What will exactly happens at startup?

Answer (score 3):

First, [disable Fast Startup in Windows.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) That feature can cause filesystem corruption in a dual-boot configuration, and may be what's causing Boot Repair to say that it needs to repair a filesystem.

OTOH, your `/dev/sda3` is identified by partition type as a Microsoft Reserved partition, which is normally empty and is used by certain Windows partitioning tools; however, Boot Repair has identified it as a damaged ext4 filesystem. It's possible that you accidentally created an ext4 filesystem on it and then subsequently damaged it; or it may be a misidentification from random leftover data in the partition. Either way, that could be what Boot Repair is complaining about. If so, wiping it clean (as in `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda3`) is probably safe -- but don't do this unless you can be certain that it doesn't hold valuable data!

It looks as if you've booted something (your original Ubuntu install and/or Boot Repair) in BIOS mode, which is the real cause of your main problem. Unfortunately, it can be difficult to control a medium's boot mode, particularly if you're unfamiliar with how a modern EFI works. I recommend you proceed as follows:

1. Download and prepare the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. If you haven't done so already, [disable Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable)
3. Boot the rEFInd medium. It will boot *only* in EFI mode. If it fails to boot, try again, but look for some other boot option -- trying to boot it in BIOS mode will cause a failure, but it should be possible to boot it in EFI mode.
4. Test that rEFInd can boot both Ubuntu and Windows. (Some entries may be non-functional; just be sure that you can boot both OSes.)
5. Boot to Ubuntu.
6. Do *one* of the following:

   - Install the Debian-package version of rEFInd. Downloads are available from the rEFInd downloads page; or you can use the rEFInd PPA, as described later on the rEFInd downloads page. This will enable you to boot much as you did with the USB drive or CD-R, but from your hard disk.
   - Re-run Boot Repair. This will probably produce the same complaint about the partition that needs repair unless you correct the cause of the problem.

Note that you may have some lingering issues, such as extra entries in the boot menu (whether that's rEFInd or GRUB 2). You'll need to deal with those after making the main repair to get both your OSes booting.